# ASP.NET Membership Login: Redirect user after logged in

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership

I have a web site that uses Membership and form authentication:

ASP.NET Page:

```
<asp:LoginView 
    ID="HeadLoginView" ...
    <AnonymousTemplate>
        <asp:Login ID="LoginUser" OnLoggedIn="LoginUser_LoggedIn" ... >
            <LayoutTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="UserNameLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="UserName">Username:</asp:Label>
                <asp:TextBox ID="UserName" runat="server" CssClass="textEntry"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:Label ID="PasswordLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="Password">Password:</asp:Label>
                <asp:TextBox ID="Password" runat="server" CssClass="passwordEntry" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="RememberMe" runat="server"/>
                <asp:Label ID="RememberMeLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="RememberMe" CssClass="inline">Remember me.</asp:Label>
                <asp:Button ID="LoginButton" runat="server" CommandName="Login" Text="Login" style="width:100%; height:35px"/>
            </LayoutTemplate>
        </asp:Login>            
    </AnonymousTemplate>
    ...
</asp:LoginView>
```

Code behind:

```
protected void LoginUser_LoggedIn(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MembershipUser user = Membership.GetUser();
    if (Roles.IsUserInRole(user.UserName, "User"))
    {
        // Do something and redirect to user page...
    }

    if (Roles.IsUserInRole(user.UserName, "Admin"))
    {
        // Do something and redirect to admin page...
    }
}
```

The problem is that `Membership.GetUser()` always returns null. I tried to get username with `Page.User.Identity.Name` but it is always empty string. Is there a way to find username of currently logged in user or even better: define after-login behavior of `<asp:LoginView>` or `<asp:Login>`?

**Edit:**

MSDN: `Login.LoggedIn Event Occurs when the user logs in to the Web site and has been authenticated.` ([link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.login.loggedin.aspx)) So the problem is that why after authenticating user Membership.GetUser() returns null?

One of my colleagues said that instead of using `Membership.GetUser()` use `Membership.GetUser(UserNameTextBox.Text)` and it is okay because user is authenticated with this username BUT the problem is that I can not find a way to get `Username.Text`. I used `findControl()` and got error.

Any Idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the solution based on the Idea of @LolCoder:

```
protected void LoginUser_LoggedIn(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String username = (HeadLoginView.FindControl("LoginUser") as Login).UserName;

    if (Roles.IsUserInRole(username, "User"))
    {
        //...
    }
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try with this:

```
protected void LoginUser_LoggedIn(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string userName = (LoginUser.FindControl(“UserName”) as TextBox).Text;
    //// or use 
    ////  string userName = (e.Item.FindControl("UserName") as TextBox).Text;
    MembershipUser user = Membership.GetUser(userName);

    if (Roles.IsUserInRole(user.UserName, "User"))
    {
        // Do something and redirect to user page...
    }

    if (Roles.IsUserInRole(user.UserName, "Admin"))
    {
        // Do something and redirect to admin page...
    }
}
```

Comment: I got this error: `The name 'LoginUser' does not exist in the current context`. The hierarchy of objects in the page is: LoginView => AnonymousTemplate => Login => LayoutTemplate => TextBox !

Answer (score 0):

I have always used my own authentication using form authentication.

I attached the code i wrote which deals with the user's login to the system

```
 string role = system.CheckAdminLogin(txtUserName.Text, txtPassword.Text);
    if (role == Role.admin.ToString() || role == Role.manager.ToString())
    {
        Users _user = _users.GetUserByUserName(txtUserName.Text);
        if (_user.Mode)
        {
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(role, false);
            Session.Add("UserName", txtUserName.Text);
            Session.Add("UserID", _user.ID);
            Response.Redirect("System/ShowActivities.aspx");
        }
        else
        {
            lblLoginFail.Text = "your account is not authorized!";
            lblLoginFail.Visible = true;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (txtPassword.Text != "" && txtUserName.Text != "")
        {
            lblLoginFail.Text = Application["Wrong_login_data"].ToString();
            lblLoginFail.Visible = true;
        }
    }
```

As you can see the first line i am getting the user role from the database, if the user is not exist the function returns null.

Next, if the user's account is authorized then i am registering him using the FormsAuthentication class i am passing the user's role.

Next i am setting a session and redirect the user to another page.

I hope it's helpful

Comment: I have to use ASP.NET Membership.

Answer (score -1):

My answer works!

```
protected void LoginUser_LoggedIn(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

      System.Web.UI.WebControls.Login controlLogin = (Login)sender;
      MembershipUser user = (MembershipUser)Membership.GetUser(controlLogin.UserName);
      ........
 }
```

Comment: This answer could be much better, I had to go back and read the question again, and this code still leaves some things a bit fuzzy.